# Webview local image from asset zoom in , out with finger

Tags: android

i have loaded an image from asset folder and fitted the image to match my screen size and now i want to add zoom in and out feature with finger , this is not working because i made the image smaller then the actual size , i beleive if i max the size out then it works  but whats the point because it makes it harder for users to keep scrolling left and right to read.

so i just fitted the image in a perfect position and if they wish to zoom in then they can.

here is the current code i use to load the image.

```
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", "<img src='p001.gif'  height='519' width='340'/>", "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

and now my next goal is to use finger to zoom in and out as normally we do.

Answer (score 1):

done it
this allows me to zoom in and out also move down if i have more images below

```
WebSettings settings = webview.getSettings();
        settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        settings.setSupportZoom(true);
```